# How do I respond from a Rocket handler with content type application/hal+json?

Tags: json, rust, serde, rust-rocket

I have a project written in [Rocket](http://rocket.rs) with the endpoint `/foo` that returns data in `application/json`. I'm using rocket, rocket_codegen, serde, and serde_json.

```
#[get("/foo")]
fn foo() -> Json {
    Json(json!({
        "foo": 1
    }))
}
```

This works nicely, but I need to respond with `application/hal+json` so I guess I need to write my own response, and I have failed. How do I return my JSON with the Content-Type `application/hal+json`?

Answer (score 1):

I got some help over at the projects chat and the solution was:

```
#[get("/foo")]
fn foo() -> Content<Json> {
    let r = json!({
        "foo": 1
    })
    Content(ContentType::new("application", "hal+json"), Json(r))
}
```